# Errors with UnitOfWork in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, unit-of-work

I use UnitOfWork pattern in my mvc5 project.

I have a BLL layer with services.

```
 public class StudentService
    {
        private readonly IUnitOfWork _db;

        public StudentService(IUnitOfWork uow)
        {
            _db = uow;
        }

        public IEnumerable<StudentView> GetStudentViews()
        {
            List<Student> students = _db.Students.GetAll().ToList();
            return Mapper.Map<List<Student>, List<StudentView>>(students);
        }
}
```

But when I'm trying to use this service in mvc controller I have an error: "No parameterless constructor defined for this object."

```
public class StudentController : Controller
    {
        private readonly StudentService _service;

        public StudentController(StudentService service)
        {
            _service = service;
        }

        // GET: Student
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            IEnumerable<StudentView> studentViews = _service.GetStudentViews();
            return View("Index", studentViews);
        }
}
```

I have no parameterless constructor, but how can I use my service with parameterless constructor in controller?

I use DI for UnitOf Work:

```
 public class ServiceModule : NinjectModule
    {
        private string connection;
        public ServiceModule(string connection)
        {
            this.connection = connection;
        }

        public override void Load()
        {
            Bind<IUnitOfWork>().To<UnitOfWork>().WithConstructorArgument(connection);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Seems to be issue with Dependency Injection declaration, can you check that?

Comment: I will start with renaming `StusentService` to `StudentService`.

Comment: You need to create Interface of StudentService and In your controller use that Interface and Using DI to resolve the dependency of StudentService,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"No parameterless constructor defined for this object."

This message means that you forgot to register a dependency for StudentService. That's why it ignored the constructor

```
public StudentController(StudentService service)
        {
            _service = service;
        }
```

and then it started to look for another constructor which is a parameterless constructor.

What I suggest is that you should create interface IStudentService

```
public class IStudentService
```

and make StudentService implements IStudentService

```
public class StudentService: IStudentService
```

Then in your ServiceModule

```
public class ServiceModule : NinjectModule
    {
        private string connection;
        public ServiceModule(string connection)
        {
            this.connection = connection;
        }

        public override void Load()
        {
            Bind<IUnitOfWork>().To<UnitOfWork>().WithConstructorArgument(connection);
            Bind<IStudentService>().To<StudentService>();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved the problem:

**StudentModule**

```
public class StudentModule : NinjectModule
    {
        public override void Load()
        {
            Bind<IStudentService>().To<StudentService>();
        }
    }
}
```

**Global.asax :**

```
 public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
           ///

            //dependencies
            NinjectModule serviceModule = new ServiceModule("connection");
            NinjectModule studentModule = new StudentModule();
            var kernel = new StandardKernel(studentModule, serviceModule);
            DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new NinjectDependencyResolver(kernel));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This error is not due to UnitOfWork. It's happening because of your controller `StudentController` and checks the constructor of that controller

```
public StudentController(StudentService service)
```

Your controller requires `StudentService` instance and You doesn't register any dependence for that `StudentService` class. Asp.Net MVC controller requires no parameter constructor or if you've any dependency then that needs to be resolved before controller creation.

The solution is to make an Interface for `StudentService` class.

```
public interface IStudentService
{
     IEnumerable<StudentView> GetStudentViews();
}
```

and update your `StudentService` class to implement that Interface

```
public class StudentService : IStudentService
{
    private readonly IUnitOfWork _db;

    public StudentService(IUnitOfWork uow)
    {
        _db = uow;
    }

    public IEnumerable<StudentView> GetStudentViews()
    {
        List<Student> students = _db.Students.GetAll().ToList();
        return Mapper.Map<List<Student>, List<StudentView>>(students);
    }
}
```

Update your DI registration code to register this dependence.

```
public class ServiceModule : NinjectModule
    {
        private string connection;
        public ServiceModule(string connection)
        {
            this.connection = connection;
        }

        public override void Load()
        {
            Bind<IUnitOfWork>().To<UnitOfWork>().WithConstructorArgument(connection);
            Bind<IStudentService>().To<StudentService>();
        }
    }
```

Update your `StudentController` and use `IStudentService` instead of `StudentService`.

```
public class StudentController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IStudentService _service;

        public StudentController(IStudentService service)
        {
            _service = service;
        }

        // GET: Student
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            IEnumerable<StudentView> studentViews = _service.GetStudentViews();
            return View("Index", studentViews);
        }
}
```